# react-native-camera-roll: IOS: Trimmed videos with Photos app on iPhone

Tags: ios, react-native, video, trim, camera-roll

I use Photos app on IOS to trim my video (iPhone 13). I use Camera roll like this:

const assets = await CameraRoll.getPhotos({ first: 30, assetType: assetType || 'Photos', include: ['playableDuration'] });

My original video is 51 sec long, but I trim it to 19 (change start time and end time). Playable duration returns 19 sec, and that's okay. However, when I pass the url to rn-video and play it, it plays full video, also, when I upload the video (rn background upload, axios or node fetch) it uploads full video version.

I want to fetch the trimmed version of the video.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.